# how to match hostname machine

Tags: linux, grep, solaris

please advice how to match the following `hostname`

machine `hostname` Should be according to the following rule

```
<a-z word ><number><a-z character/s>
```

real example

```
star1a
linux25as
machine2b
linux5a
solaris300C
unix9c
```

please advice how to machine these  `hostname` with grep

I have for now this syntax

```
hostname | grep -c '[a-z][1-2][a-z]'
```

but these syntax not work on all my examples

on solaris the option egrep -E not works

```
hostname | grep -E '\b[a-z]+[0-9][a-z]+'
grep: illegal option -- E
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .
Broken Pipe
```

try the second option ( on solaris machine ):

```
hostname
swu2a
hostname | grep "^[a-z]\+[0-9][a-z]\+$"
```

not matched!!!

I also try this:

```
hostname
swu2a
hostname | grep '[a-z]\+[0-9]\+[a-zA-Z]\+'
```

NOT MATCHED!!!

Comment: show also lines that should not match, as well as indicate if this should match the whole line or just part of it.

Comment: see example in my question

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Also, try to indicate if the leading spaces are really supposed to be there or just a typo when writing the question.

Comment: hi from some reason on solaris its not work maybe it will beter to try with perl one liner - can you please advice with perl line liner?

Comment: As fedorqui writes, your examples has various numbers of space in front of the text. Pleas edit post if that is not correct.  Like change `<space>swu2a` to `swu2a`. If you do not now how to dot it, I can use some sec to fix it.

Comment: I think it will beter to use perl one liner because maybe grep opn solaris isnt like grep on linux

Comment: @maihabunash fixed your post, if its not correct, undo it.

Comment: You have almost 20 questions in Perl, maybe you can try yourself. Also, as you have asked so many questions, consider adding proper requirements. Otherwise, many people gets involved without really knowing what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an `awk` using same regex as the `grep` posted here uses.

```
awk '/[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+/' 
star1a
linux25as
machine2b
linux5a
solaris300C
unix9c
```

If you need to make sure there is nothing else in the line, only the words above, use:

```
awk '/^[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+$/'
```

`^` marks start of line.
`$` marks end of line.

Comment: Why do you use awk for a typical grep job?

Comment: @hek2mgl That is not for me to answer.  I just added it since OP did have problem with `grep`

Comment: Ok, got it. Was just wondering why awk should be used here. Unfortunately I don't have a Solaris system to test a grep there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern:

```
grep '^[a-z]\+[0-9]\+[a-zA-Z]\+$'
```

Note that you can use the the return value of `grep` to decide whether the pattern matches or not, you don't need to use the `-c` option. Like this:

```
if [ hostname | grep '^[a-z]\+[0-9]\+[a-zA-Z]\+$' >/dev/null 2>&1 ] ; then
    echo "host name OK"
fi
```